# how to extract and update class file from a jar?

Tags: java, jar, compilation

this is what i need to do:

1) extract files from a .jar archive

2) take two of them, decompile them, make some updates and then re-compile them

3) make the jar archive again

Basically the problem is that after my updates i cannot compile the class anymore because i ve got a lot of errors about dependencies by the javac compilator.

i'm extracting files from .jar using archive manager of linux 
i'm decompiling classes using [java decompiler online](http://www.javadecompilers.com)
i'm trying to compile the file again using the command javac

thanks please help me

Comment: Hi! Where did you stuck?

Comment: The problem is that once i make the updates to the java file i cannot compile it anymore due to problem about dependencies